# Access denied with localhost

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I was trying to set a password for my phpmyadmin as there was a notification asking me to do so. when I did it using sql optionI typed this code

```
`SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('your_root_password`');
```

when i executed this code it denied me access to my phpmyadmin.

I get this error every time I visit localhost/phpmyadmin now

```
"#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".
```

any way to fix this?

Comment: your mysql have a password?, reinstall it, because u probably messed with the installation

Comment: not my sql but I used mysql option in phpmyhost to set a password for phpmyadmin but that denied me access to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open "config.inc.php" on your PMA folder.

add this line to prompt the authentication before login

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; */
/* $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; */
```

OR manually define your authentication by this line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourpassword';
```